# can someone explain why the second code works but not the first?

Tags: python

```
given_list = [7,5,4,4,3,1,-2,-3,-5,-7]
total1 = 0
i = 0
while given_list[i] < 0 and i < len(given_list):
    total1 += given_list[i]
    i += 1
print(total1)
```

I am trying to add all the negative numbers together. The code above gives the answer 0.The code below gives the answer -17 (the correct answer). Why do they give different answers? To me it looks like both of them are the same, just written differently. I am clearly misunderstanding something. Can someone help me wrap my head around this?

```
given_list = [7,5,4,4,3,1,-2,-3,-5,-7]
total1 = 0
i = 0
while i < len(given_list):
    if given_list[i] < 0:
        total1 += given_list[i]
    i += 1
print(total1)
```

Comment: The code `i += 1` is missing one indentation level, it should go inside the while block.

Comment: Inline `given_list[i] < 0` is false 'cause first element of list is 7 which is larger than 0 not less. Therefore this gives false and while loop not execute.

Comment: `given_list[i] < 0 and i < len(given_list)` is wrong, it should be `i < len(given_list) and given_list[i] < 0`. Otherwise you could use an `i` which is out of bounds of the list.

Comment: Just to give you a third option: `print(sum(value for value in given_list if value < 0))`

Answer (score 1):

The first `while` breaks at the first element of the list, because the condition evaluates to false. This happens because `given_list[i] < 0` at Index 0, the value is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `given_list[i] < 0`.
Your array will not pass this condition and not enter the loop.
This will only pass if you negative numbers are first and then the others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's because the while loop first condition (while given_list[i] < 0) is false for the first element itself (7) and the loop doesn't execute itself.
You can try printing the current looped element for more clarity

```
given_list = [7,5,4,4,3,1,-2,-3,-5,-7]
total1 = 0
i = 0
while given_list[i] < 0 and i < len(given_list):
    total1 += given_list[i]
    print(given_list[i])
    i = i + 1
print(total1)
```

You can also try the above code minus the given_list[i] < 0 and print each looped item.

Answer (score -2):

The first program doesn't work because a `while` loop breaks when it's condition is false. So as soon as the loop enounters a positive number in the list, `given_list[i] < 0` becomes false and the loop breaks.

What you want is to go through the whole list and check each element whether it is positive or not without breaking the loop.

Comment: `i` gets incremented inside the while loop, therefore this answer is wrong

Comment: You are right, I misread the code